# Tuning hidden layer and neurons using neuralnet package

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network

I am currently training ANN with single hidden layer. I want to adjust the amount of neuron inside the model using the code below (adapted from http://uc-r.github.io/ann_regression)

```
NN_FLUX1 <- neuralnet(formula = CO2_Flux ~ .,
                        data=trainSet_flux,
                        hidden=c(1:30),   # number of vertices (neurons) in each hidden layer
                        algorithm = "rprop+",   # resilient backprop with weight backtracking,
                        err.fct = "sse",       
                        act.fct = "tanh", 
                        threshold = 0.05,       
                        linear.output=FALSE,
                        rep = 30)
```

I want to confirm

```
hidden = c(1:30)
```

is that means the neuralnet will perform the grid search from one to 30 neurons to find the best ANN models ? am I wrong?

Comment: Why test this at all? It is already proven that the network will approximate asymptotically perform more accurate with the number of hidden units. One usually tests different network architectures e.g. number of hidden layers, instead of testing multiple networks with the same architecture (e.g. just one hidden layer). How to define the best model? Are you doing regularization?

Comment: I've using grid search with different approach (using caret; with grid search layer1 = c(1:50), layer2 = 0, layer3 = 0) and compared it with manual tuning (I'm new to ANN and R actually). I found my ANN models seemingly possessed unstable and irregular RMSE (ranging from 0.2 to 0.8) when I tried it manually using random numbers of neurons with incremental trend. This is the main reason why I test it using grid search (Then, the result looks good with RMSE = 0.13). How do you suggest? why this is happen?

Comment: How many samples do you have? Are you using cross validation? This this RSME from data not already being used for training?

Comment: I have small sample size (N = 60 in total after cleaned from outliers). I calculated RMSE using 30% data (30% from 60 = 18 obs). for caret, I used tenfold CV repeated 10 times (surely with other 70% data). Actually I used small sample size for initial training in ML and DL, gradually learn to handle some 800  to 1000 obs data in the future.

Comment: Am I handle this badly?

Comment: Yes, the RMSE is calculated from separated validation data (30% obs)

Comment: I would not go with an ANN for under ~1k samples. Their output is usually not very reliable.  LOOCV is more useful than repeated CV if you have the resources for training. CV is only needed if you have too few samples. Samples are more valuable than repeats or folds.

Comment: thankyou very much for your valuable comment and suggestion. your suggestion push me to learn more about this interesting stuff (which is new in my field). Maybe this is not correlated with ANN model that you suggest, but I noticed some paper also used low sample numbers (under 100 obs also), particularly in modeling species distribution (insect, etc) using ML. from my point of view, I am agree with you. Just like my cases, their prediction is quite unreasonable. how do you think?

Comment: Biological data is expensive to collect and complex to analyze. Most of the papers are reviewed by biologists and not mathematicians. ANN was maybe the only model with some results. It's not good but the best what can be done here.

Comment: thankyou very much. Your answer give me some light about how peer review process of predictive modeling, in particular with species distribution. nice to discuss with you.